# How can I get data from two vectors?

Tags: java, vector

I'm new to Java and the first to use vector.

input

```
A aaa bbb 

C dddd eeee fff
```

when you want to `vec.elementAt(1);`

The output will be:

```
C ddd eee fff
```

I don't know how to use two vectors(name and word) implement it.

My thoughts are like this:

```
       vec[0]             vec[1]
name   A                  C
word   aaa      bbb       dddd     eeee     ffff
       wvec[0]  wvec[1]   wvec[0]  wvec[1]  wvec[2]
```

I have been thinking about this problem for a week

This is my code:

```
public class Name {
     Vector <String> name = new Vector<String>();
     ....
    while ( ... ) {
      vec.add(name);
      ...
    } // while
}


public class Word {
    Vector <String> wvec = new Vector<String>();
    while ( ... ) {
      wvec.add(word);     
    } // while
}
```

Comment: I would suggest you to create a custom object.

Comment: I really don't think we should use a Vector in 2020. Use ArrayList instead. If you need thread safety use a concurrent list implementation from util.concurrent.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the scenario like below:

Word Class:

```
class Word{
    char name;
    Vector<String> words;
}
```

TestClass:

public class TestClass {
public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    Word word = new Word();
    word.name = 'A';
    word.words = new Vector<String>();
    word.words.add("aaa");
    word.words.add("bbb");
    
    Word word1 = new Word();
    word1.name = 'B';
    word1.words = new Vector<String>();
    word1.words.add("dddd");
    word1.words.add("eeee");
    word1.words.add("fff");
    
    Vector<Word> wordVector = new Vector<>();
    
    wordVector.add(word);
    wordVector.add(word1);
    System.out.println("Name" + "-----" + "Words");
for (int i = 0; i < wordVector.size(); i++) {
    System.out.print(wordVector.get(i).name + "------");
    for(int j=0;j<wordVector.get(i).words.size();j++) {
        System.out.print(wordVector.get(i).words.get(j)+" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
}
```

}

Comment: Must it be implemented in main ?

Comment: I think it is possible to use other classes without main?

Comment: What should be implemented in main ?  and Yes you can use the class without main method. You are using them as a custom object.

Comment: why the output have```[ , ]``` ? Can I delete it ?

Comment: Yes can modify it accordingly.

Comment: Can you tell me how to modify it ? and is this automatically generated by the system ?

Comment: Can you show me the output once please , what are you getting , so that I can guide you properly?

Comment: output:
A-----[aaa, bbb]

B-----[dddd, eeee, fff]

Comment: Ok , how you want the output to be?

Comment: without ```[ , ]```.  A-----aaa bbb B-----dddd eeee fff

Comment: You are always welcome . Happy Learning ! If you are satisfied with the answer , could you please help upvoting it? It will help others if they land on this question seeing for solution similar to this

Answer (score 0):

Example implementation which parses string lines and prints data may be as follows:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Example {
    
    static class Line {
        private String name;
        private Vector<String> words = new Vector<>();
        
        public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
        public void addWord(String word) { this.words.add(word); }
        
        public String getName() { return name; }
        public Vector<String> getWords() { return words; }
        
        public String toString() {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append("name:\t").append(name).append('\n');
            sb.append("words:\t");
            for (String word : words) {
                sb.append(word).append('\t');
            }
            sb.append("\n     \t");
            for (int i = 0, n = words.size(); i < n; i++) {
                sb.append("w[").append(i).append("]\t");
            }
            sb.append('\n');
            return sb.toString();
        }
    }

    private static Line parseLine(String src) {
        if (src == null) return null;
        Line line = new Line();
        String[] arr = src.split(" ");
        if (arr.length > 0) {
            line.setName(arr[0]);
            for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
                line.addWord(arr[i]);
            }
        }
        return line;
    }
    
    public static void main(String []args) {
        
        String[] rawLines = {
            "A aaa bbb",
            "C dddd eeee fff"            
        };
        
        Vector<Line> lines = new Vector<>();
        for (String rawLine : rawLines) {
            Line line = parseLine(rawLine);
            lines.add(line);
            System.out.println(line);
        }    
    }
}
```

This code prints the following output:

```
name:   A
words:  aaa bbb 
        w[0]    w[1]    

name:   C
words:  dddd    eeee    fff 
        w[0]    w[1]    w[2]
```

Comment: The code are pretty well, but I want to use two vectors, instead of List

Comment: `List` in my code is holding theiraw strings as input, it is not critical, I updated the answer to use array of Strings.